# NSTimer not firing when it should

Tags: ios, animation, nstimer

I have a table view that is broken up into alphabetic sections.  I am displaying an animated banner in a UIImage View in the footer of each section, and need to determine which image is displayed when the UIImage View is clicked.  I set a timer right before I make the call to startAnimating.  The timer is to fire every 5 seconds, at the same rate that the animation changes, but the timer is firing much faster.  Sometimes it will fire 2 or 3 times within that 5 second period.  Here is the code where I start the timer and the animation:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger) section {

...

    imgAdBar = [[bannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(footer.frame.origin.x,footer.frame.origin.y,footer.frame.size.width,footer.frame.size.height)];

    imgAdBar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [animationArray objectAtIndex:0]]]; 
    [imgAdBar saveBannerArray:animationArray];
    [imgAdBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    imgAdBar.animationImages = images;
    imgAdBar.animationDuration=[images count]*5;
    imgAdBar.animationRepeatCount=0;
    timerCount=0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRunning:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [imgAdBar startAnimating];
    [footer addSubview:imgAdBar];
    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
return footer;
}
```

And here is the selector:

```
-(void)timerRunning:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
NSLog(@"timerCount=%d",timerCount);

imgAdBar.timerCount=timerCount;
if (timerCount==numAnimationImages) {
    timerCount=0;
}
NSLog(@"currentImage=%@",[animationArray objectAtIndex:timerCount]);
timerCount++;
}
```

I plan to use that timer to index into my image array so that I can tell which is displayed.  Anyone have any idea why it's not firing when it should?  Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Add `NSLog` in `viewForFooterInSection:` to see if you're scheduling the timer multiple times. If you want it to fire in sync with the animation, why don't you latch onto the animation ending event instead, with the `animationDidStop:` implementation in the delegate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately I'm not in front of my Mac right now but will try that after work.  But, I think you may be on to something.  Since I have the NSTimer call in my viewForFooterInSection procedure, I can have more than one footer displayed on the screen at a time.  So, I guess I would somehow have to specify different timers for each section and have a different selector for each?  Or, I would need to pass the section to the selector and increment separate counters?  Sorry, I'm very new to ios...would animationDidStop be called once all the images are displayed?

Comment: it is probably firing a few times because `viewForFooterInSection` method is called for every footer and every time that footer is displayed on a screen

Comment: @user1292943 `animationDidStop` method of an animation delegate is called when the animation reaches the end state (i.e. when the `animationDuration` is exhausted). By the way, the methods that you use to set up animation should not be used in iOS 4.0 and later; switching to `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` should let you provide an action to take upon completion of your animation without the timer.

Comment: How much segments are there in your view??

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys.  Dilip Rajkumar, there can be at most about 20 segments in my view, but only a few would be displayed at one time.  @dasblinkenlight, I'm not sure what it would buy me if I fire the timer at the end of the animation.  I need to use the timer to determine which image is displayed at a particular time, and the timer value would be used as an index into the animation array.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @user1292943 You don't fire a timer at the end of the animation, you can use the end of the animation notification *instead* of the timer, to provide you "a tap on the shoulder" to increment your `timerCount`.

Comment: Hey there @dasblinkenlight. Say if I have 10 images that are to be displayed in the animation (which would repeat), and each image is displayed for 5 seconds, 50 seconds would elapse before the end of the animation.  If I use the end of the animation to increment my timer count, I would not know when a particular image is displayed, only when all of them have been displayed.  If someone clicks on one of the footers after, say, 14 seconds, how can I know which was displayed after 14 seconds?  It would work if only one footer is displayed at a time, but I could potentially have 2 or 3 displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use NSTimer as an property ...
Since  `viewForFooterInSection`  is called several times for many sections you have to invalidate before you reinitialize it or you have to check for null following is the code..
**Invalidate:**

```
    NSTimer *timer; // declare in ViewDidLoad
  // code in viewForFooterInSection
    [timer invalidate];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                         target: self
                         selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
                         userInfo: nil
                         repeats: YES];
```

**Check for nil**

```
if (timer == nil) {

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                                                 target: self
                                               selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                                repeats: YES];
    }
```

Hope it should help..

Comment: Thanks a bunch Dilip, I'll try this out this afternoon when I get home from work.

Comment: Hi @Dilip Rajkumar, what you posted definitely did help.  However, I have an issue when there is more than one section displayed on the screen at one time.  The timer won't increment because the code in the footer for each section invalidates the timer.  Any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: Ohh.. Just now I understood the problem.. you are trying to display images at the footer of each section.. which changes timely..  Each footer has to be in their own way in displaying images.. Please correct me if I am wrong..  I will work out and let you know in few hours..

Comment: Hi @Dilip Rajkumar, yep, I think you got it.  Each footer will have its own animation array of banner type images.  When a user clicks on any of those images, there will be a segue to a page that will show detailed information about the particular banner that was clicked.  I need to figure out which banner was displayed in the the particular footer that was clicked.  The timer approach seems like the best approach, the problem is when there are potentially multiple animations in view at the same time.  I guess I'd need to use separate timers?  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Yes I too thought the same..  Just initialize and use the timer for each and every segment i.e. with out checking nil and  invalidate .. If it does not fix..  I will try later this day..

Answer (score 1):

Declare an NSTimer as property in your header file

```
@propterty (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *someTimer;
```

In the line where you fire the timer

```
someTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRunning:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Don't forget to release it in -(void)viewDidUnload

```
[someTimer release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not use the value of `timerCount` unless there is a click, you do not need to update it on timer: it is sufficient to store the time at the moment when you start animation. Knowing that each image is shown for five seconds, you can calculate the index of the image being displayed by taking the difference, in seconds, between the time of the click and the time when you started the animation, dividing it by five, and taking the remainder of the division by the total number of images.

Say you have ten images, each displaying for five seconds in a loop. Let's also say that the animation has started at `08:15:51`. Now let's say there's a click at `08:19:23`, or `212` seconds after the animation has started. After dividing by five you get `42`; taking the remainder of the division by ten, you get `2`. Therefore, you know that the user has clicked on the third image in the animation loop (as usual, indexes start from zero).

Comment: That totally makes sense @dasblinkenlight.  I will try that when I get home from work this afternoon.  Thanks so much for all your help!!